# Removing values prior to some specific index rowwise

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I currently have data which looks like the following:

| ID | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 | Var_4 | Var_5 | RemovePrior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 30 | 25 | 35 | 40 | 3 |
| 2 | 40 | 50 | 45 | 55 | 60 | 2 |
| 3 | 60 | 70 | 65 | 75 | 80 | 4 |
| 4 | 80 | 90 | 85 | 95 | 85 | 5 |

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 Var_1 = c(20, 40, 60, 80),
                 Var_2 = c(30, 50, 70, 90),
                 Var_3 = c(25, 45, 65, 85),
                 Var_4 = c(35, 55, 75, 95),
                 Var_5 = c(40, 60, 80, 85),
                 RemovePrior = c(3, 2, 4, 5))
```

My goal is to—for each row—fill in the variables to the left of the variable with the suffix indicated by "RemovePrior" with NA. For example, for ID = 1, RemovePrior takes on the value 3, hence I wish to have Var_1 and Var_2 set to NA. The following is the intended result:

| ID | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 | Var_4 | Var_5 | RemovePrior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | NA | 25 | 35 | 40 | 3 |
| 2 | NA | 50 | 45 | 55 | 60 | 2 |
| 3 | NA | NA | NA | 75 | 80 | 4 |
| 4 | NA | NA | NA | NA | 85 | 5 |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `base R`

```
nm1 <- startsWith(names(df), "Var")
df[nm1] <- NA^(col(df[nm1]) < df$RemovePrior) * df[nm1]
```

-output

```
> df
  ID Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Var_4 Var_5 RemovePrior
1  1    NA    NA    25    35    40           3
2  2    NA    50    45    55    60           2
3  3    NA    NA    NA    75    80           4
4  4    NA    NA    NA    NA    85           5
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(across(starts_with("Var_"), 
   ~ case_when(readr::parse_number(cur_column()) >= RemovePrior ~ .x )))
  ID Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Var_4 Var_5 RemovePrior
1  1    NA    NA    25    35    40           3
2  2    NA    50    45    55    60           2
3  3    NA    NA    NA    75    80           4
4  4    NA    NA    NA    NA    85           5
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(Var_1:Var_5,
    ~ if_else(which(cur_column() == names(df[-1])) < RemovePrior, NA_real_, .x)))

#>   ID Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Var_4 Var_5 RemovePrior
#> 1  1    NA    NA    25    35    40           3
#> 2  2    NA    50    45    55    60           2
#> 3  3    NA    NA    NA    75    80           4
#> 4  4    NA    NA    NA    NA    85           5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way how we could do it:
Using `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -c(ID, RemovePrior)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(value == lag(value, unique(RemovePrior)-1), NA, value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name,
    values_from = value
  )
```

output:

```
     ID RemovePrior Var_1 Var_2 Var_3 Var_4 Var_5
  <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1           3    NA    NA    25    35    40
2     2           2    NA    50    45    55    60
3     3           4    NA    NA    NA    75    80
4     4           5    NA    NA    NA    NA    85
```